# In Android- how to use different main.xml without losing current state?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make the orientation changed without losing the current state of the activity.

I use **android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"** in manifest.xml, then it doesn't load the xml file for landscape, rather chnages the orientation of hte portrait main.xml.

I want layout-land/main.xml when orientation changed to landsacpe and vice-verse without restarting the activity.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```
  @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

for further Assistance or Detail 
Use Handle [Runtime Change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to some extent

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

// Checks the orientation of the screen
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
   //Do your action
   } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //Do your action
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The activity will be restarted when the orientation changes you will have to implement `onSaveInstanceState()`and `onRestoreInstanceState()`